# How can I split long text in tabular? without using a package

Tags: tables, xetex

I want to split the column in b1 into two. but when I use \ it gets slipped, how can I solve this problem. (without using new package) (overleaf)

Before:

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Year}  \\ 
    a1 & Long text, TEST  & 2016  \\ 
    b1 & Very very very very very very very very very very very long text, TEST  & 2019 \\
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

---

After:

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Year}  \\ 
    a1 & Long text, TEST  & 2016  \\ 
    b1 & Very very very very very very very very very \\ very very long text, TEST  & 2019 \\
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Look up the `p{width}` column specifier. And why the insistence on no packages?

Comment: I am writing an academic thesis. We were told that we need to add a new package to the overleaf format determined by our department teachers.

Comment: Inside tables, \\ is redefined to start a new row. You have to change column type to `p{}` and then use `\newline` instead of  \\ if you want to issue a line break.

Comment: @theoyuncu8 that only makes sense for packages not already in overleaf. We generally never recommend packages that are not widely available to every user and thus are already available in overleaf.

Comment: @daleif I know, but if they wanted to, they would have already added it to this format, so I don't want to include some additional cases by saying usepackage.

Comment: @Celdor not working sorry

Comment: There is one more question I would like to ask. I have a wiki address that I write in the url. but it doesn't read the parenthesis at the end and when I click on it it says page not found. how can i fix this

howpublished = "\url{https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programlama_dili)}"

Comment: when i click on it it doesn't read the last parenthesis, if i add another letter it reads the parenthesis but this time the url is wrong

Like this; https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programlama_dili

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `tabularx`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXl}
    \textbf{Title} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Year}  \\ 
    a1 & Long text, TEST  & 2016  \\ 
    b1 & Very very very very very very very very very \newline very very long text, TEST  & 2019 \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I think it is better to leave out the `\newline` and let LaTeX decide where to break the line.

Regarding the URL: `howpublished =` suggests it is part of a bibliography. Please give the bib entry and a complete minimal document ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)) to show how you use it, because using the url in the text works correctly, at least when I prefix it with `http://` (maybe the problem is that you left that out, because strictly speaking, yours isn't a URL).

Comment: hello thank you very much for your comment but is there any other way to do this without using the tabularx package?

Comment: See @daleif's comment above: use a `p{something}` column spec. But then you have to make a gues about the `something`, e.g. `p{10cm}`.